# Self injection in spring and testing it using mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

We are using Spring 5.2.x (with Spring Boot 2.3.x) & Mockito 3.3.x.

I need to call a `@Transactional` method in my service from within it. Hence I had to resort to self injection.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsCostructor // lombok
public class MyClass {
    private final dep1;
    private final dep2;

    @Autowired
    private MyClass self;

    public void someMethod() {
        self.someTransactionalMethod();
        // do something
    }

    @Transactional
    public void someTransactionalMethod() {
        // do something
    }
}

public class MyClassTest {
    @Mock
    private dep1;
    
    @Mock
    private dep2;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void someMethodTest() {
        // NPE when calling self.someTransactionalMethod()
    }
}
```

From the code it is relevant that we are using constructor injection using lombok. For obvious reasons, I cannot declare the instance variable `self` as `final`, hence using `@Autowired` for this one. The class works fine but I see issues with the unit test.

There are 2 parts to my question -

1. Regarding the way I am doing self injection - is this the best way of doing self injection? Is there any other approach recommended by the authors of Spring framework in recent versions of Spring?
2. Mockito is by no means able to inject the self bean into the object of CUT (Class Under Test). Is there a way to achieve this in a clean way?

I have already considered the following:

1. Introduce a setter for `self` and use it to inject self in setup method. Don't want to add a setter only for tests.
2. Use `ReflectionUtils` to set `self`. Reflection seems unclean to me. I would prefer `@Setter` over this.
3. Tried using `@RunWith(SpringJunit4Runner.class)` but that failed as expected because I am not creating a proper context and stuff.

Comment: Might this be a good case for refactoring the service and someTransactionalMethod() into a different class so that it can be mocked?

Comment: `someTransactionalMethod` is well defined in this service. Only for testing, dont think it good idea to refactor.

Answer (score 6):

In your `setUp()` method call:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(myClass, "self", myClass)
```

You'll also need to add [spring-test](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test) as a dependency if you haven't already.

Comment: I have already mentioned that this is not the approach I would want to go ahead with.

Comment: Self-injection in itself is a hack, so I think the proposed answer is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

If injecting self references is difficult or you need ReflectionTestUtils to fulfill it, it is because the test is not a pure unit test and in your case because the service does not have a well defined interface. If we change the service to implement an interface and change the test to be a pure unit test, the code becomes as follows and the problems disappear:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    @Inject
    private MyInterface self;

    @Override
    public void someMethod() {
        self.someTransactionalMethod();
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Object someTransactionalMethod() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not implemented yet");
    }
}
```

And the test becomes:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJunitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private MyInterface self;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass service;

    @Test
    public void someMethodShouldCallSelf() {
        when(self.someTransactionalMethod()).thenReturn("test");
        service.someMethod();
        verify(self, times(1)).someTransactionalMethod();
    }
}
```

Now the test for `someMethod()` follows unit testing principles by actually testing only the code in `someMethod()` instead of including `someTransactionalMethod()` in it's complexity. Then you write separate unit tests for `someTransactionalMethod()` to ensure that it functions correctly.